# Laravel 4.1 Request::is for active menu not working

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to make a menu active depending on route in laravel 4.1, my attempt:

```
<li
   {{{ (Request::is('/core') ? 'class="active"' : '') }}}><a href="{{{ URL::to('/core') }}}">Control Panel</a>
</li>
```

My route:

```
 Route::get('/core', 'CoreController@Showindex');
```

This is not throwing any errors just simply ignored. any help is appreciated.

Comment: does this routing work?

Comment: @revo this route works fine.

Comment: Have you tried `Request::is('core')`?

Comment: @DamienPirsy not working neither :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

changed to:

```
<li
   {{{ (Request::is('/core') ? 'class=active' : '') }}}><a href="{{{ URL::to('/core')  }}}">Control Panel</a>
</li>
```

from `'class="active"'` to `'class=active'`

This working fine for `<li>` tag but not `<a>` tag, needs to be used like so:

```
<a href="{{{ URL::to('core') }}}" class="list-group-item {{{ (Request::is('core') ? 'active' : '') }}}">Overview</a>
```

Answer (score 9):

In Laravel 4.2:

**By name:**

```
<li class="{{ Route::is('user') ? 'active' : ''}}">Profile</li>
```

router.php

```
Route::get('/user/{id}', ['as' => 'user', 'uses' => 'UserController@profile']);
```

**By url:**

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('user/*') ? 'active' : '' }}">Profile</li>
```

Answer (score 6):

you can do like Ahmed Siouani said and use Request if you use a true url or if you use a route you can do something like this :

```
class="{{ URL::route('my.route') === URL::current() ? 'active' : '' }}"
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using the triple brace `{{{  }}}` syntax, which is causing any output to be auto-escaped into HTML entities. That's messing with your output (HTML attributes aren't supposed to be escaped).

Use the triple braces when outputting data that is user-generated, or other instances where you do not control it and can't rely on it being 100% secure. If you're displaying URLs, classes, and other items that you are generating yourself, use the standard echo syntax `{{  }}`

**Update for Laravel 5:** The raw, unescaped Blade syntax is now `{!!  !!}`. By default, Laravel 5 will escape both the original double and triple brace structures.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Laravel 9.* Year 2022

```
<a class="nav-link {{ (Request::is('home') ? 'active' : '') }}" href="{{ url('home') }}">
```