# Laravel: request::is() and request::patch()

Tags: laravel, request

Can somebody explain me difeerence between 
Request::is()
and
Request::patch()
??
I used request::is in my code to active navbar like this, but i saw that somebody use too request::patch

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
 <ul class="nav">
  <li class="{{ Request::is('/') ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="/">#
    </a</li>
     @foreach($categories as $category)
     <li class="{{ Request::is($category->name) ? 'active' : '' }}">
      <a href="/{{$category->name}}">{{$category->name}}</a></li>
                    @endforeach
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I just checked the api and there is no `patch` method on request. From the doc : The `is ` method allows you to verify that the incoming request path matches a given pattern. You may use the * character as a wildcard when utilizing this method

Comment: You're right. But thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I think you mean `path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Side patch Request :**

> patch request says . only send the data which one you want to update
>   and it won't effecting or changing other data . so no need to send all
>   value again . just i want to update my first name so i need to send
>   only first name to update .

**In Side Is Request :**

1. https://indigotree.co.uk/laravel-4-using-request-is-named-routes/
2. [Laravel 4.1 Request::is for active menu not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808016/laravel-4-1-requestis-for-active-menu-not-working)

**Example**

```
<li
   {{{ (Request::is('/core') ? 'class=active' : '') }}}><a href="{{{ URL::to('/core')  }}}">Control Panel</a>
</li>
```

> and Check  'class="active"' to 'class=active'

This working fine for `<li>` tag but not `<a>` tag, needs to be used like so:

```
<a href="{{{ URL::to('core') }}}" class="list-group-item {{{ (Request::is('core') ? 'active' : '') }}}">Overview</a>
```